# Get otvdm (aka winevdm) to run 16-bits applications automatically

Tags: windows, 64-bit, emulation, 16-bit

I am working on the a project that requires me to run a Makefile which calls on several 16-bit .exe scattered in my F drive. I have looked into using otvdm (aka winevdm) to run the 16-bit applications though I am looking for a way to get them run to automatically when a called on. The current setup of otvdm is having manual selection from the user. What I want is when a 16-bit application is called, it would use otvdm to run the application without me getting involved. Looking for ideas to do this or work around it?

My 64-bit Windows 10 OS rejects any 16-bit applications from running.

Comment: How does the makefile launch children, CreateProcess or ShellExecute? Does it use full paths?

Answer (score 1):

From the readme at https://github.com/otya128/winevdm .

> How to install
>
> Download or compile
> Run "install" shortcut or right-click on install.inf and select "Install"
> You can execute Win16 binaries directly!>
>
> If the registry is initialized by Windows Update, perform the above procedure again.
>
> You can uninstall it by running uninstall.reg.

You probably want to use the (no console) link.